# angular ng-model-options getterSetter not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use ng-model-options getterSetter. But I can't get it to call my model function.

```
<input id="idShowDisabled2" type="checkbox" ng-model="myObj.Trev" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />Show disabled feeds
```

It works if I just use a regular model: ng-model="ShowDisabled". I have left this line as well.

```
<input id="idShowDisabled" type="checkbox" ng-model="ShowDisabled" />Show disabled feeds
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/qc5qtg5q/26/

Comment: which version of angularjs are u using?

Comment: The fiddle uses 1.2.1

Comment: I see this feature requires 1.3. I guess that is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I'm also expecting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature uses 1.3 but it is not difficult to implement in 1.2 using ng-change